# Isomorphic as $R$-modules v.s. Isomorphic as abelian groups

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, abelian-groups, noetherian, local-rings

Let $(R,\mathfrak m, \mathbb Q)$ be a Noetherian local ring. Let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module such that for some integer $n\ge 0$, there is an isomorphism of abelian groups $M \cong \mathbb Q^{\oplus n}$.

My question is: Is $M$ Isomorphic, as an $R$-module, to a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb Q$? i.e., is it true that $\mathfrak m M=0$?

Comment: What is the $R$-action on your direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @Qi Zhu: well $R/\mathfrak m \cong \mathbb Q$ ... so $\mathbb Q$ has a natural $R$-module structure ...

Comment: Ah, I didn't read attentively enough that $\mathbb{Q}$ is the fraction field. My bad, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No : take $R=\mathbb Q[\epsilon] = \mathbb Q[X]/(X^2)$; then $R$ itself satisfies your hypotheses.

Comment: That's clever ... do you happen to know any example in positive dimension (i.e. $R$ is not Artinian) ?

Comment: Mhm I suppose $\mathbb Q [| X |]$ should work: it still satisfies the hypotheses, and $\mathbb Q[X]/(X^n)$ is $\mathbb Q^n$ as an abelian group but certainly not as an $R$-module.

Comment: Any module satisfying the hypotheses must be Artinian, and any Artinian $(R,\mathfrak{m},k)$ with $k=\mathbb{Q}$, other than $\mathbb{Q}$ itself, is a counterexample, taking $M=R$.